# Get multiple file in .net from form send from axios

Tags: .net, axios, form-data, iformfile

My payload have these:

[image]

and I want to get data from medias, but in server it is null

[image]

I have try `IEnumerable<IFormFile>` and `IFormFileCollection` but it still null.

Get data from medias in form.